# How to return a value from an instantiated object in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, delegates, reverse-geocoding

I created an object that receives a coordinate and suppose to return a placemark after reverse geocoding it. Problem is that this method is a-synchronic, so I need a way to return the placemark once it was found. In my view controller I call this:

```
[getzip reverseGeocodeCurrentLocation:coordinate];
```

where getzip is an instance of an object that implements this (which is still empty in my case....):

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
```

Now, once I get into reverseGeocoder:didFindPlacemark, how can I return the placemark back to the viewcontroller?

I tried to do the same thing as I saw in some examples being done with LocationManager, where a locationUpdate method is being called from locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation, and implementing the locationUpdate in the viewcontroller, but it did not work. In other words, I did that:

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
[self.delegate setPlacemark:placemark];
}
```

and implemented setPlacemark in the viewcontroller, but it doesnt get to setPlacemark from some reason (BTW, the placemark is correct once I call setPlacemark:placemark within reverseGeocoder).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `self.delegate` is not `nil`?

Comment: "`[self.delegate setPlacemark:placemark];` and implemented `setPlacemark` in the viewcontroller, but it doesnt get to `setPlacemark` from some reason" Do you set the view controller as your delegate?

Comment: How do I set the view controller as delegate? Sorry, new to objective c...

Comment: Yes! it is nil...what do I do now? :(

Comment: @albertamg: I think I know what you meant, yes I did set it as delegate: @interface MyMap : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, MyLocationControllerDelegate, GetZipcodeDelegate>, where GetZipcode is the class in question.

Comment: @TommyG Making your view controller conform to the `GetZipcodeDelegate` protocol means your view controller *can* be your delegate, not that it *is*. You must set the `delegate` property to your view controller. If `getzip` is an instance of the class that executes `[self.delegate setPlacemark:placemark];`, you would do: `getzip.delegate = self;` in your view controller.

Comment: @TommyG: That just makes it conform to the GetZipcodeDelegate protocol, which means it promises to respond to the messages that a delegate must. In order to set the delegate, you either have to hook the object's `delegate` outlet in a nib or put something along the lines of `object.delegate = someInstanceOfMyMap` somewhere in your code, where `someInstanceOfMyMap` is the instance of MyMap you want as the object's delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comments, `self.delegate` is `nil` when `[self.delegate setPlacemark:placemark];` in `reverseGeocoder:didFindPlacemark:` is executed. Therefore, nothing happens.

You must set the `delegate` property to your view controller before `reverseGeocoder:didFindPlacemark:` gets called. If the variable `getzip` in your view controller is an instance of the class that implements `reverseGeocoder:didFindPlacemark:` (`GetZipCode`?), you would do this in your view controller:

```
getzip.delegate = self;
```

As I said in my comment, by making your view controller conform to the `GetZipcodeDelegate` protocol means your view controller *can be* the delegate because it responds to the messages that the object that is delegating will potentially send to its delegate. It does not mean that it *is* the delegate.

Comment: Oh my lord, thank you so much! I would never have guessed that. I guess I am missing the fundamentals of objective C, since I dont really fully get yet this whole delegate business. Thanks again, that did it!

Comment: You are welcome :) Have a look at these documents [1](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) [2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18). They do a good job explaining the delegation pattern.